# How can you make the user change the content of a variable in Python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am just writing a simple currency converter program, and the one problem that i am facing is that i can't think how to have the user change the content of the variable. Below is an the basic bit:

```
def D2Y():
    def No():
        newconv=float(input("What is the rate that you want to use: "))
        amount=float(input("How much do you want to convert: $"))
        conversionn=round(amount*newconv,2)
        print("¥",conversionn)
        return (rerun())
    def Yes():
        conrate2=float(97.7677)
        amount=float(input("How much do you want to convert: $"))
        conversion=round(amount*conrate2,2)
        print("¥",conversion)
        return (rerun())
    def rerun():
        rerun=int(input("Do you want to go again?\n1 - Yes\n2 - No\nChoice: ")) 
        if rerun==1: 
            return (main()) 
        else: 
            print("Thank you for converting") 
    conrate1=int(input("The currency conversion rate for Yen to 1 US Dollar is ¥97.7677 to $1\n1 - Yes\n2 - No\nDo you want to use this rate?: "))
    if conrate1==1:
        return (Yes())
    else:
        return (No())
```

I dont know how you do it. I dont mind if you get rid of the def functions.

Comment: I'm confused by your question. You're using input and you're converting the resulting strings to floats. What variable are you trying to change other then the one's which are already being manipulated?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that does away with the functions and allows you to modify the exchange rate:

```
rate = CONVERSION_RATE = 97.7677
while True:
    print "The currency conversion rate for Yen to 1 US Dollar is ¥%.4f to $1" % rate
    print 'Select an option:\n1)Modify Conversion Rate\n2)Convert a value to dollars\n0)Exit\n'
    choice = int(raw_input('Choice: '))
    if choice == 0:
        print("Thank you for converting")
        break
    if choice == 1:
        try:
            rate = float(raw_input("What is the rate that you want to use: "))
        except ValueError:
            rate = CONVERSION_RATE

    amount = float(raw_input("How much do you want to convert: $"))
    print "¥", round(amount * rate,2)
    print '\n\n'
```

In use, it looks like this:

```
The currency conversion rate for Yen to 1 US Dollar is ¥97.7677 to $1
Select an option:
1)Modify Conversion Rate
2)Convert a value to dollars
0)Exit

Choice: 2
How much do you want to convert: $1.00
¥ 97.77

...

Choice: 1
What is the rate that you want to use: 96.9000
How much do you want to convert: $1.00
¥ 96.9
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to have it permanently changed in the code itself?

Comment: You're asking if you can change source code, through the execution of the code?  Then no, unfortunately, you cannot.

Comment: If you're interested in having persistent values, though, then your best bet is to use external files to save these values--changing the source code during run-time is not possible.